# How to create nested dictionary using two dictionaries in which value of first dictionary is equal to the key of second dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

In my Project, 2 dictionaries have been created in below format :-

```
dict1 = {'A':['B'], 'C':['D']}
dict2 = {'B':['X'], 'D':['Y']}
```

And I'm looking for below expected result :-

```
dict3 = {'A':{'B':['X']}, 'C':{'D':['y']}}
```

I want to print value of **'A'**, **'B'** and **'X'** in 3 columns in HTML table but somehow I'm not able to do so. Please help me out to get this.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you:

```
dict1 = {'A':['B'], 'C':['D']} 
dict2 = {'B':['X'], 'D':['Y']}

new_dict = dict()

for val1, val2 in dict1.items():
    new_dict[val1] = {val2[0]:dict2[val2[0]]}

new_dict
{'A': {'B': ['X']}, 'C': {'D': ['Y']}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input I was able to apply the logic and the get the required values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
>>> dict3 = dict([(k,{v[0]:dict2[v[0]]}) for k, v in dict1.items()])
>>> dict3
{'A': {'B': ['X']}, 'C': {'D': ['Y']}}
```